# Webpack npm ERR Missing script: build; (WINDOWS 10)

Tags: node.js, windows, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My bf and I were making a haiku checker during school today. Everything was working fine but when I cloned his repo i'm getting a "npm ERR! missing script: build;" on my windows 10 PC

Any help will be much appreciated and I can provide more info

Additional errors

```
npm ERR! Haiku@1.0.0 start: `npm run build; webpack-dev-server --open --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Haiku@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is my package.json

```
 {
      "name": "Haiku",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
        "build": "webpack --mode development",
        "start": "npm run build; webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
        "lint": "eslint src/*.js --fix"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.18",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
        "eslint": "^4.18.2",
        "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
        "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.99.0",
        "karma": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "karma-jquery": "^0.2.2",
        "karma-webpack": "^2.0.13",
        "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
        "webpack": "^4.0.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.1",
        "syllable": "^3.0.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: did you run npm install before you try to run npm run build?

Comment: yes! I ran npm install and I switched between several Node versions still getting the missing script ERR